# LuaLaTeX engine, babel and pdfx package

Tags: luatex, babel, pdfx

There is one error with the combination of `spanish` `babel`, `pdfx` package, and LuaLaTex engine, how it is very easy to test with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdfx}   

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
P_{\max}=0.1
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The `.log` contains

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
/
l.11 P_{\max
          }=0.1
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\xdef 
l.11 P_{\max
          }=0.1
? 
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
\xdef 
l.11 P_{\max
          }=0.1
? 
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
/
l.11 P_{\max
          }=0.1
? 
! Missing = inserted for ifdim.
<to be read again> 
/
l.11 P_{\max
          }=0.1
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
/
l.11 P_{\max
          }=0.1
?
```

and a stream of similar complaints all for the same single line.

Comment: What exactly is the error? The document compiles fine for me when I run it with LuaLaTeX (or pdfLaTeX, as a matter of fact I get an error about `CreationDate is not properly supported; PDF validation may fail.` with XeLaTeX). The output looks OK as well (I get "máx" for `\max` and "0,1" for `0.1`) but I assume that is intended if `spanish` is passed to `babel`. Can you please include the relevant bits of your `.log` file and a screenshot of the output (if appropriate).

Comment: Thanks for the `.log`. The only relevant difference I could spot on first glance is that my `pdfx` package is older than yours. I'll investigate ... *edit*: Yup. Updated `pdfx` (which wasn't up to date for some reason) and I can now reproduce the error.

Comment: At least my incompetence in keeping my packages up to date strongly suggests that `pdfx` is the culprit. I had `pdfx` v1.6.1 and things worked, after an update to v1.6.3 things don't work any more. So it probably broke in between those two versions.

Comment: I think so also. Thanks for the edition of the question.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems a bug in `spanish`, not in `pdfx`. I have to investigate.

Comment: pdfx added some code to change mathaccents and this breaks with spanish. You could add `\unaccentedoperators` as a workaround.

Comment: @JavierBezos pdfx has added a \pdfx@mathaccentV and then redefines mathaccentV.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, and `\mathaccentV` exits form math mode and then enters again, and here is where `spanish` fails. This is a valid trick, and therefore I have to blame `spanish`, not `pdfx`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in `spanish`, which has popped up after a change in `pdfx`. As a workaround, after loading `babel`, write:

```
\makeatletter
\def\es@fetchenc{%
  \begingroup
    \count@\escapechar \escapechar=\m@ne
      \edef\es@a{\expandafter\string\the\textfont\mathgroup}%
      \expandafter\split@name\es@a////\@nil
    \escapechar=\count@
    \@expandtwoargs\in@{////}{\f@size}%
    \ifin@\else
      \PackageError{spanish}{%
        Non-NFSS font name. The current math font (\es@a)\MessageBreak
        doesn't follow the NFSS conventions. I'll use the\MessageBreak
        default \string\i\space for \string\dotlessi,
        but expect a wrong output.}%
      {Find where this font has been (re)defined, and fix it.}%
      \def\f@encoding{OT1}%
    \fi
  \bbl@exp{\endgroup\def\\\f@encoding{\f@encoding}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: The workaround resolves the problem. I'm going to accept the solution and I'm going to vote up